# Nextcloud does not start after installation

Tags: permissions, client, nextcloud

I have installed the Nextcloud client from the Ubuntu software collection on my Ubuntu 18.04. system. But when try to start it I get the following mesaage in the terminal:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/snap/nextcloud/21026/apache/logs': Operation not permitted
Making sure nextcloud is setup...
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/sockets': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/sockets': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/locks': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/pids': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp/sockets': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud': Operation not permitted
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/tmp': Permission denied
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/snap/nextcloud/21026/nextcloud/extra-apps': Operation not permitted
Waiting for PHP...
```

and nothing happens. 
What shall I do to make it work?

Comment: I have seen yourself answer to your question and this post: [NextCloud is Currently Broken in Ubuntu 21.04, But a Fix is Coming](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/04/nextcloud-is-broken-in-ubuntu-21-04-but-a-fix-is-coming) i am trying to add the Appimage file link to this question for fast answer for others, so the Appimage [link](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients) is: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFUIn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFUIn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by downloading the [Appimage file](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients) and starting it directly.